# Decrypting with Java SecretKeySpec

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I don't know what is wrong, but I crypt an image with a key, but when I use the same key to decrypt it, it doesn't work, I guess the problem is in the SecretKeySpec() these are the methods crypt and decrypt

```
public void crypt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    // Encrypt

    byte [] data = {90, 52, 50, 52, 48, 54, 54, 51, 52, 51, 50, 51, 49, 51, 54, 51};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length, "AES");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalKey.getEncoded())+data);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalKey.getEncoded())+data);
    String cleartextFile = this.lien;
    String ciphertextFile = this.lien;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphertextFile);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

    int i;
    while ((i = fis.read()) != -1) {
        cos.write(i);
    }
    cos.close();
}

    // Decrypt
public void decrypt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException{

        //csetCodeCrypt(result.getBytes(6));
        byte [] data = {90, 52, 50, 52, 48, 54, 54, 51, 52, 51, 50, 51, 49, 51, 54, 51};
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length, "AES");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalKey.getEncoded()));
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalKey.getEncoded()));
    String cleartextFile = this.lien;
    String ciphertextFile = this.lien;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cleartextFile);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

    int i;
    while ((i = fis.read()) != -1) {
        cos.write(i);
    }
    cos.close();
}

}
```

And this is the use of these methods in the main

```
image.crypt();
image.decrypt();
```

These are the results:

```
[90, 52, 50, 52, 48, 54, 54, 51, 52, 51, 50, 51, 49, 51, 54, 51][B@ed5d9d 

[90, 52, 50, 52, 48, 54, 54, 51, 52, 51, 50, 51, 49, 51, 54, 51][B@ed5d9d

[90, 52, 50, 52, 48, 54, 54, 51, 52, 51, 50, 51, 49, 51, 54, 51]

[90, 52, 50, 52, 48, 54, 54, 51, 52, 51, 50, 51, 49, 51, 54, 51]
```

What I did is to crypt and decrypt an image at the same time with the same key, but the image is only crypted, and I can't read it anymore.

I don't get errors when compiling this code.

Comment: What does setCodeCrypt() do? And what is the result of all those println() calls? And how is this going to work once this program has exited and the secret key has been lost?

Comment: i cleared the code and edited the question, now the code is clearer, i included the results, please read it again thank you

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you trying to open the wrong file by any chance? NB This code overwrites the original cleartext image file, is that what you really want? NB (2) This code would be a lot more efficient if you use `read(byte[])` and `write(byte[], 0, count)`, where `count` is the result of `read().`

Comment: i know that it edits the original image file, that is the perpose. Where should i use the read(byte[]) and write(byt[],0, count)? i mean instead of what?

Comment: I didn't say 'edits the original file', I said 'overwrites'. If that is its purpose, it is futile, because, when the code is working, the original input file is equal to the final result file. You should use those `read/write` methods instead of reading and writing a byte at a time: what else? I tried it on 536870911 random bytes, several times, cannot reproduce.

Comment: i'm sorry but could you please help me edit the code and use the read/write methods, i'm getting some complications in doing it thank you

Comment: 'Getting some complications' doesn't convey anything useful. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce.

NB This code would be a lot more efficient if you used buffered I/O:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192; // or more if you like
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

at both ends.

Comment: what does buffer reffers to? does it refer to the key?

Comment: Sigh. It refers to a `new byte[8192],` as I said above. Is the word 'buffer' really so mysterious? Nothing to do with the key. Why would you read plaintext or ciphertext into a key?